# Reading pdfs on iPad without storing them permanently

Tags: ipad, pdf, reading-list

I'm a software developer and my software is generating a lot of PDF reports which I know will consume a lot of space if downloaded. My clients use iPads. Is there a way they can view PDFs without having to store them permanently on the iPads (temporarily store them while viewing and auto-delete them when closed)?

Answer (score 1):

The Safari browser by default just views the PDFs. That should be sufficient. 
It also has the option to "Save to iBooks" so you can access it later.

Comment: The question asks how to avoid using space permanently for this. Using Safari would indeed store it in its cache unless explicitly cleared, wouldn't it?